# Centered slide carousel with bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, bxslider

I require a reponsive, height adjustable carousel showing a hint of the next and previous content for a mobile website. After some research I came around the bxslider, which almost fullfills all my needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/8greL/1/

Unfortunately, I was unable to write a carousel and make it adapt to the width automatically. At the moment I was just able to force my way through ugly, static hacks suchs as this one...

`$('.bx-wrapper').first().css('max-width', '240px');`

Maybe my choice of library or my approach is wrong, but I have no clue how to get it done without writing a carousel by my own...

Comment: Did you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/8greL/4/?

Comment: Hi MarsOne,
nope... I want the content of the prev/next slide to be visible by totally 10px each regardless of the screen width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a solution by adding/changing the calculation of the slide width and the amount the slides have to be slided inside of the library.

After I finalized my local changes I'll share it on github. :)

Update: I uploaded my changes into github ~> https://github.com/Gumbagubanga/bxslider-4/tree/develop

Comment: Took me a bit longer. Changes have been implented in within my bxSlider fork (WIP): https://github.com/Gumbagubanga/bxslider-4/tree/develop

Comment: If you edit the answer I can change my vote to +1, it's locked at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the width(to max-width) of the bxslider so the responsive can go fluid...

But what I did to fix current state is this:

```
.galleryWrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 240px;
}

.galleryWrapper .bx-viewport {
padding-left: 20px;
 width: inherit !important
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/8greL/3/)

Comment: I guess I was unclear what the end result should be. The images (and the carousel) should stretch out to the full width of the body/containing element. Thus, I don't want to give a fixed width to the slides.